# How to concatenate 2d arrays from generator in Julia

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia, concatenation, generator

So I'm struggling on what I think should be a pretty straightforward operation.

I understand that in Julia if I wanted to concatenate 2 2D arrays I could do this

```
# 10x3 Matrix
a = rand(10, 3)
b = rand(10, 3)
c = rand(10, 3)

# 30x3 Matrix
c = [a ; b; c]

# 30x3 Matrix
d = vcat(a,b,c)
```

But I don't know how to generalize this to a generator format
What I want to do is this :

```
multi_2d = [rand(10,3) for _ in 1:3]
matrix = vcat(multi_2d)
```

But I am left with a 3 element array that I can't seem to reshape.

Would love any guidance on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the splat operator `...` to apply the function `vcat` to the sequence of arrays in `multi_2d`:

```
vcat(multi_2d...)
```

Comment: or `reduce(vcat, multi_2d)`.